# C Read colors from Bitmap

Tags: c, colors, bitmap

Im'm loading the color of a pixel and writes a one-byte variable. When I want to read this color (for red pixel) should get the result: 255 However, the value is: 4294967296. From this it follows that the value has been recorded in 32-byte variable. Why does this happen?

```
struct RGBpix{
 char R;
 char G;
 char B;
}typedef RGB;
```

...

```
RGB **data=(RGB **)malloc(sizeof(RGB *)*Picture.biWidth);
    for(i = 0; i < Picture.biWidth; i++){
        data[i] = (RGB*) malloc(sizeof(RGB) *Picture.biHeight);
    }
```

...

```
for(i=0;i<Picture.biWidth;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Picture.biHeight;j++){

        fread(&data[i][j].R, 1, 1,bmpFile);
        fread(&data[i][j].G, 1, 1,bmpFile);
        fread(&data[i][j].B, 1, 1,bmpFile);
        }

    }
    printf("%Ld", data[0][1].R);
```

Comment: ***Dat kast from `void *`!!!***

Comment: Your format specifier for `printf()` is invalid, and results in Undefined Behaviour. The '`L`' flag is only valid with the a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifiers, and tells `printf()` that the argument is a `long double`. Try changing that to `printf("%d\n", data[0-][1].R)` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` appears to be a signed type on your machine.  Use `unsigned char` to avoid the sign extension.